# Reading power supply value in the datasheet ; -0.3 V to 6 V ? ; Unclear

Tags: operational-amplifier, datasheet, infrared

[image: Datasheet of TSSP77038 from Vishay]

I am working on IR module and was referring to datasheet from Vishay. While looking at supply voltage it showed -0.3 to 6 V. I am unable to understand -0.3 V, how -0.3V can power the circuit.

Then I looked at Op-Amp from TI, the datasheet, shows same pattern.
Pl suggest or point me to reference which I can read.

Does it mean 6-0.3 V = 5.8 V max, but then they could have written it.

[image: Data sheet TI, op-amp]

Comment: Look at the "ELECTRICAL AND OPTICAL CHARACTERISTICS" table to find the real recommended operating conditions.

Comment: It can't. You are looking at the ABS MAX not the operating range.

Answer (score 2):

The chart you show are absolute maximum ratings. You should never exceed these, or damage to your device is expected. It doesn't mean that the device will operate at those values.

For example, a supply voltage of 0 will not damage your device. But the device won't operate at that supply voltage either. However, a supply voltage more negative than -0.3V may be expected to damage the device.

Comment: Beat me to it.  That's pretty much exactly what I was going to write.

Answer (score 0):

The Absolute Maximum Allowed supply voltage is -0.3V or +6V. A supply more negative than -0.3V or more positive than +6V will damage or destroy it. The specifications for a TSOP1738 (you did not say which IR receiver) recommend a +5V and 0V supply.

The maximum allowed input voltage for your opamp is no more negative than -0.5V more negative than its negative supply voltage or no more positive than +0.5V more positive than its positive supply voltage. Input voltages between the positive and negative supply voltages will not cause damage. Read the specifications to see what input voltages are recommended since some opamps have a limit.

Comment: Datasheet is for TSSP77038.